# List of paired elements in python

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.4

I have to create a list of pairs from 2 lists of same length 'n'. So the pairs would look like [(list1[1],list2[1]),(list1[2],list2[2]),...,(list1[n],list2[n])]. The resultant list of dictionaries should be of length 'n'.However my records are getting repeated and from the length of the resultant list it seems like a cartesian product is getting generated.Given below is the code:

```
    pairs=[]
for y in range(len(predicted_label)):
    pair={score_tweets[y],predicted_label[y]}
    pairs.append(pair)
```

Please note that both the lengths of scored_tweets = length of predicted label.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip).

```
zip(score_tweets, predicted_label)
```

returns an iterator of tuples `(score_tweets[i], predicted_label[i])`. If you need a list, use `list(zip(score_tweets, predicted_label))`, as suggested by @cfh.

This is not a list of dictionaries, but why do you need dictionaries with single (key, value) pairs?

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator by default. If you actually want a list, you can simply do `list(zip(score_tweets, predicted_label))`.

Comment: @cfh oops, overlooked that. I'll correct it in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do it:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = ['a','b','c','d','e']
pairs = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
  pairs[x[i]] = y[i]
print(pairs)
```

It gives output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

In more pythonic way

```
pairs = {x[i]: y[i] for i in range(len(x))}
```

or use `zip`.

Comment: This is much too verbose and not Pythonic at all. Check the `zip` answer.

Comment: @cfh I answered it like this so that OP can identify mistake in his code.